# Indexed-based numbering in pseudocode

Tags: python, arrays

I'm studying a-level computer science and my text shows array pseudocode declarations, some starting at 1 and others 0. Can anyone tell me why this is the case. Please note that I am studying Python.

```
DECLARE List1 : ARRAY[1:3] OF STRING  // 3 elements in this list 
DECLARE List2 : ARRAY[0:5] OF INTEGER // 6 elements in this list 
DECLARE List3 : ARRAY[1:100] OF INTEGER // 100 elements in this list 
DECLARE List4 : ARRAY[0:25] OF STRING // 26 elements in this list
```

Comment: This pseudocode is not Python, and the lists described are not consistent with Python slicing behaviour. (In Python, a `[1:3]` slice would be 2 elements, not 3.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are languages that use either or both, and some algorithms are easier to express with one or the other. For instance, a textbook heap uses 1-based indexing. C and Python use 0 based indexing, Pascal and Ada let you choose, Lua and Matlab use 1 based. In practical terms, you mostly need to be aware which is used in the language you write.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(array) lists the conventions used in a few languages. One bit of trivia that's not in there is the C way to find the number of elements in an array: `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])`. It's rarely used because C's calling conventions strip size information by demoting arrays to pointers, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In languages like for example Pascal you actually decide what is the lower and upper bound for indexing. This is the notation the text is using.

In Python and most other programming languages instead the first element is always at index 0 and when declaring an array you only say what is the number `N` of elements.

In a few badly designed programming languages the first element is instead at index 1.